# WPF Refresh CollectionView without explicit recreation (Refresh() method call)

Tags: c#, wpf, collections

Is it possible to 'refresh'(update) a view without explicit Refresh() method call? The problem is that it recreates a whole collection, and on UI, selected row becomes unselected. I have a complex list view (each row contains another sub-listview) and when I call Refresh(), selection in sub-rows disappears. Clearing SortDescriptions and adding them again manually doesn't work for me (It seems that both Clear() and Add() sort description's methods calls Refresh() internally)

So, any chance to get view updated without it recreation?

My situation :
Using Dispatcher.Timer I'm updating all the properties for each item manually (to avoid selection disappear), then update one item's list-type property (property with another one collection, it is updating 'manually' too) and then I need to refresh a view somehow, when I call Refresh() on sub-collection, everything is OK, but I also need to refresh a top-level collection too, to get sort descriptions applied to top-level collection, which was probably changed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found a solution in this great blog post : [DrWPF](http://drwpf.com/blog/2008/10/20/itemscontrol-e-is-for-editable-collection/)

Comment: Link only answer... you should copy the relevant portions here before that link dies.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use [ContinuousLinq](http://clinq.codeplex.com/) to keep the view sorted/grouped at all times.